# Retrieve Table Data and store Array in AWS Dynamodb Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I successfully listing table name in AWS DynamoDB.

All table name also print in debug console.

But problem is how to fetch table data ?

My item count always 0 but in db its show 5 records.

Here is my code.

```
    let atVal = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    atVal.S = "testC"
    let condition = AWSDynamoDBCondition()
    condition.comparisonOperator = AWSDynamoDBComparisonOperator.EQ
    condition.attributeValueList = [atVal]

    let myDic: [String: AWSDynamoDBCondition] = ["testC": condition]
    let query = AWSDynamoDBQueryInput()
    query.tableName = "test"
    query.keyConditions = myDic
    query.limit = 1


    dynamoDB.query(query).continueWithBlock {
        (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        let results = task.result as! AWSDynamoDBQueryOutput

        let myResults = results.items
        print("object: \(myResults!.description)")

        return nil
    }
```

This output shows this response.

```
AWSiOSSDK v2.4.5 [Debug] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:63 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body:
```

AWSiOSSDK v

```
2.4.5 [Debug] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:63 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body:
{"Count":0,"Items":[],"ScannedCount":0}
object: []
```

Can anybody help me ? How to get and retrieve data in AWS ?

Anyone provide demo AWS DynamoDB ?

Thanks

Comment: It says that there are no items `Count: 0, Items: []`. Are you sure you have data at all? Can you query using a client to check wether there is data or not?

Comment: what is the output of `print(myrResults)` instead of `myResults!.description`?

Comment: @VladimirNul Yes data is there.

Comment: @h44f33z output of print Optional([])